# Why my postgis ST_Intersects and ST_Azimuth based query is slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, postgis

I have a table that contains approximately 300k routes with start point, end point, route as polyline type and polygon type.

I made a self join to find out the intersections of the routes with each other but the query is very slow. Even if I run `explain analyze` there is no return from this analyze.

```
CREATE INDEX gist_index_geo_poly_gon ON geo_akin USING gist (geo_polygon)
CREATE INDEX gist_index_geo_poly_line ON geo_akin USING gist (geo_polyline)
CREATE INDEX idx_id ON geo_akin USING btree (id)
```

I have indexes as above and the query is below:

```
 select 
 ST_Intersection(second.geo_polyline, first.geo_polygon)  as intersection,
from geo_akin first
   , geo_akin second
where second.id != first.id
  and abs(sin(ST_Azimuth(second.actual_start_point, second.actual_end_point))- sin(ST_Azimuth(first.actual_start_point, first.actual_end_point)))<1
  and abs(cos(ST_Azimuth(second.actual_start_point, second.actual_end_point))-cos(ST_Azimuth(first.actual_start_point, first.actual_end_point)))<1
  and st_intersects(second.geo_polyline , first.geo_polygon);
```

Below is my `EXPLAIN` result:

```
   Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..45452.35 rows=128519 width=64)
  ->  Seq Scan on geo_akin found  (cost=0.00..2584.67 rows=3167 width=17077)
  ->  Index Scan using gist_index_geo_poly_line on geo_akin first  (cost=0.15..2.97 rows=1 width=4244)
        Index Cond: (geo_polyline && second.geo_polygon)
        Filter: ((id <> second.id) AND (abs((sin(st_azimuth(actual_start_point, actual_end_point)) - sin(st_azimuth(second.actual_start_point, second.actual_end_point)))) < '1'::double precision) AND (abs((cos(st_azimuth(actual_start_point, actual_end_point)) - cos(st_azimuth(second.actual_start_point, second.actual_end_point)))) < '1'::double precision) AND _st_intersects(geo_polyline, second.geo_polygon))
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added the Explain result.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Why there is poly line and polygon? Maybe you can use `second.id > first.id`to avoid reverse comparison?

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza I missed this point. Now I am adding this condition to avoid the reverse comparison. Because one of them is the collection of the lines(routes) and one of them is just an area. I want to find the intersection.

Comment: How slow is your query. Can you elaborate about poly lines and polygons? I don't see routes as polygons. Maybe isn't relevant for the problem but would like to have the whole picture to see how I would approach to it myself. Maybe add some examples. And what are the sin, cos formula for?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza everything is clear. The basic problem is that I want to find the intersections of all of the records with each other. The sin and cos formula are to determine these routes are in the same direction.

Comment: Again how slow is your query? And can you provide some examples. I work a lot with routes and polygons andI probably can give you a better suggestion if understand what is the problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the query is running for almost 15 hours and we still could not get any response. As you suggested before I changed my query with ''second.id > first.id''. In my geo_akin table a row contains basically two points as start and end point. Besides these, a row contains also the geo_polyline column from starting point to the ending point and geo_polygon column is the polygon from started point to the ending point.

Comment: So why you try to intersect polyline with polygon? why not just polyline vs polyline?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it is just about our business flow. We should make it like polyline vs polygon.

Comment: Well that doesn't tell me much. Again can you give some data examples. I'm thinking several scenarios and possible optimization I  can use. But don't want invest much time if you won't be able to use it.

Comment: If you run the query with just the  `WHERE second.id > first.id AND INTERSECT()` how much time take?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What I can see is your self join of a 300k table give you 90.000 millions intersections. My suggestion is try to filter the join to only overlapping polygons and then find if they intersect.

If you add X1, Y1, X2, Y2 for the bounding polygon and create an index with (ID, X1, Y1, X2, Y2) you can find overlapping polygons very quickly

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(b.geo_polyline, a.geo_polygon) AS intersection
FROM geo_akin a
JOIN geo_akin b
  ON a.X1 <= b.X2
 AND a.X2 >= b.X1
 AND a.Y1 <= b.Y2
 AND a.Y2 >= b.Y1
 AND a.id < b.id
WHERE abs(sin(ST_Azimuth(b.actual_start_point, b.actual_end_point))
        - sin(ST_Azimuth(a.actual_start_point, a.actual_end_point))) < 1
  AND abs(cos(ST_Azimuth(b.actual_start_point, b.actual_end_point))
        - cos(ST_Azimuth(a.actual_start_point, a.actual_end_point))) < 1
  AND st_intersects(b.geo_polyline, a.geo_polygon);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we have already have the st_intersects built-in function in where clause to find whether there is an intersection. Do you think to add these points and put them as conditions makes big different?

Comment: Yes, I think so. And if doesnt work we try something else.